# Query mail messages using Office 365 Rest API

Tags: office365

Is there a way to query mail messages on their subject or body using a wildcard? I'm aware of the following option:

```
/messages?$filter=Subject eq 'Jordan Example'
```

However, I'm looking for a way to use a contains parameter. Something like:

```
/messages?$filter=Subject contains 'ordan'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to do substring match, try :

/messages?$filter=substringof("ordan",Subject) eq true

For more functionalities, see http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/